# jquery checkbox click inside a link area?

Tags: jquery, events, checkbox

Hellow

If there is a checkbox inside a link, I want to make the checkbox selectable as well.
But now, only a link is clicked and only the checkbox is not selected.

How can I give the same event as selecting a link even when the checkbox is selected?
I'm using jquery 2.1 as well.

```
<a href="#" class="linkme>
  <div>
  <span>Click here</span>
  <input type="checkbox" class="my-checkbox"> Check Me
  </div>
</a>

<script>
$(".linkme").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); 
   e.stopPropagation();
   var chk = $(this).find("input").is(":checked");
   if(chk){
       $(this).find("input").prop("checked", false);
       console.log("ok");
   } else {
       $(this).find("input").prop("checked", false);
       console.log("not click");
   }
});
</script>
```

If I click a link area [class name = "linkme"]
The checkbox is checked as I want.

But when I check the checkbox alone, nothing happens.
How can I make the checkbox selectable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code,

```
<a href="#" class="linkme">
  <div>
    <span>Click here</span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="my-checkbox"> Check Me
  </div>
</a>

<script>
$(".linkme").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  
  var chk = $(this).find("input").is(":checked");
  
  if (chk) {
    $(this).find("input").prop("checked", false);
    console.log("unchecked");
  } else {
    $(this).find("input").prop("checked", true);
    console.log("checked");
  }
});

$(".my-checkbox").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
</script>
```

Comment: It's amazing. I haven't slept for days because of this...Thank you very much :)